# In TOAD, is there a way to comment out arbitrary blocks of code (i.e not whole lines)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, toad

The shortcut to comment out code in TOAD (11.6.16)  is  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

However, the problem is that it does not let you comment out an exact selection within a block of code. So, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> it simply comments out all the lines of the code , so I can't comment out a specific column with `/* .. */` via keystroke.

Is there a way to run the arbitrary `/* .. */` commenting  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can get there by a lesser known feature. The Search and Replace macro. In the Editor hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to get to the replace dialog. On the toolbar click the right-most button to get to the macro editor. Copy the entire contents, below, and paste into that dialog within the left side tree. It'll create a macro for you that I made. Hit close, etc. to get out of that dialog. Now, in the editor whenever you make your selection you can invoke this by using the little dropdown next to the replace button on the Editor toolbar. It's not exactly as easy as using keyboard shortcut, but it works and Search/Replace macros are super powerful for more complex work. Here's the dropdown I'm referring to.

[image]

Here's the code to copy/paste. Grab everything from (and including) "object" through to (and including) the "end"

```
object TComponentCollection
  Items = {
    545046300F5474645265706C6163654D6163726F000B446973706C61794E616D
    65060D436F6D6D656E7420426C6F636B0D49676E6F72654661696C757265080A
    4D6163726F47726F7570080C5365617263684F726967696E070D736F456E7469
    726553636F70650C577261705365617263686573080F50726F6D70744F6E5265
    706C616365080A5465787446696E6465720A9C000000545046300F5474645465
    78745265706C61636572000D4361736553656E7369746976650811526567756C
    617245787072657373696F6E090A5365617263685465726D0606283F73292E2A
    0F536561726368446972656374696F6E07097364466F72776172640A57686F6C
    65576F726473080B5265706C6163655465787406062F2A24302A2F135265706C
    6163655769746854656D706C617465080000054974656D730A32000000545046
    301F547464437573746F6D5365617263685265706C6163654D6163726F4C6973
    7400054974656D730A0000000000000000}
end
```

Comment: Now, with that being said, this feature is possible with a keyboard shortcut in 12.7, but due to naming conflict with the CTRL+B feature it's hidden and inaccessible. It can be made visible for a future release.

Comment: Wait, so what is that giant hex code there? this looks really different ??!?

Comment: It's a string representation of a complex object, a search/replace macro in this case. Toad supports this in a few places so you can easily share your creations with others. The Automation Designer and Search/Replace macros are two that come to mind. If you follow the steps in my answer it'll make more sense.

Comment: Here's the thread that kicked off the macro feature with another user's request for what she needed to do. It opens up a lot of possibilities and multiple search/replace actions can be chained together. http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/i/editor/42a72715-e436-4847-9887-54622c0dfecd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Toad Data Point 6.1.2.24 (which for this TOAD product is a very recent version) and would like to have block commenting style (/* .. */) available instead of how it line comments everything highlighted. Unfortunately "Search and Replace Macros" doesn't seem to be a feature in it, and none of the keyboard shortcuts mentioned do the same thing (or do anything in some cases). It's very hard to find correct information for various specific TOAD products since a lot of people just call what they are using "TOAD" that is both correct for that specific product, and still current (not changed in the most recent version).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).